# Reading an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression

Tags: javascript

I've been using this pattern to organize common methods used in my JavaScript without truly understanding it.

```
(function(newSubNamespace) {
 newNamespace.someNewFunction = function(args){
    //do something
 }
}(window.appNamespace.newSubNamespace = 
  window.appNamespace.newSubNamespace || {},
  jQuery));
```

I get that this is adding the functions defined like `someNewFunction` to `window.appNamespace.newSubNamespace` and that the `window.appNamespace.newSubNamespace || {}` creates newSubNamespace if it doesn't yet exist, but I can't figure out what the the `,jQuery` bit does.

Furthermore, if I had to name this, would it just be extending?

I've been using this pattern without fully understanding it and would like to know more.

Comment: It just passes jQuery as the second parameter to the IIFE !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `, jQuery` appears to be useless in this particular case (unless you're accessing the second argument with the `arguments` object), because your outer anonymous function doesn't take a second formal argument.

Normally, code that does this might look like

```
(function(something, $) {
   ...
}(whatever, jQuery));
```

so that jQuery is assigned into the formal argument `$` inside the anonymous function (here, an "IIFE": *immediately invoked function expression*). This is used as a way to reserve `$` for jQuery inside your IIFE, when other libraries might also try to use the `$` identifier.

Comment: IIFE = Immediately-Invoked Function Expression: you're defining and invoking a function all at the same time, with `(function (parameters) { body })(arguments);`.

Comment: "Totally useless" depends on wether or not the parameter is being used inside the IIFE, there are other ways to get the functions arguments !

Comment: It totally makes sense now. I don't know why my brain couldn't see that it was just function(arg1, arg2)! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you copy this from somewhere else and you missed the second parameter of the anonymous function. I.e. it should be

```
(function(newSubNamespace, $) {
...
```

You are doing this just to be sure that *$* sign is jQuery and not something else.